# Reset in Mealy finite state machine

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I have some issues with the reset signal in a Mealy finite state machine in VHDL. I have created a very simple Mealy FSM for easier understanding.
The FSM has two process, one synchronous for the calculation of the state, and one combinational for the calculation of the outputs and the next state. The issue I have is that when reset = '1' and input1= "11" then output1="11" when it should be output1 ="00"

This can be solved by: including the reset input in the sensitivity list of the combinational block.
Or by evaluating  the reset signal at state s0 ( for example `if input1="11" and rst = '0'then`  ). Nevertheless I didn't see these "solutions" in any literature, so there is where my doubts are.
Below is the source code.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity fsmtest is
  
  port (
    clk  : in  std_logic;
    rst : in std_logic;
    input1  : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    output1  : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));


end fsmtest;

architecture rtl of fsmtest is

  type state is (s0, s1);
  signal st, next_state : state := s0;


begin  -- rtl

  process (clk, rst)
  begin --process
    if rst = '1' then
      st <= s0;
      --next_state <= s0;
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then  -- rising clock edge
      st <= next_state;
    end if;
  end process;

  process(st, input1)
    begin  -- process

      case (st) is
        when (s0) => --initial state
          if input1 = "11" then
          next_state <= s1;
          output1 <= "11";
          else
          next_state <= s0;
          output1 <= "00";
        end if;

        when (s1) => --wait10
          if input1 = "00" then
            next_state <= s0;
            output1 <= "00";
            else
              output1 <= input1;
              next_state <= s1;
          end if;     
      end case;
  end process;
end rtl;
```

Comment: It is easier and less error prone to write a single-process state machine.

Comment: I disagree with the above statement. There are advantages to writing a single-process FSM, but I would say it is certainly less error prone to use two processes as above, one purely sequential and combinational. This is because outputs from a single-process FSM are registered (which is an advantage), but because of that, each output has to be anticipated one clock cycle in advance. This requires some kind of mental transformation between the state diagram and the HDL code, which is where errors can creep in.

Comment: Another useful feature is that you can write code like `if next_state==B then...` In a single process FSM you have to track down all cases where you go to state B. (And hope you don't forget the 'then' section if you make a change) In a split process you can just use the code above.

Answer (score 0):

When `rst = '1'` and `input1= "11"` then `output1="11"`. That's what you have written in your code. You have written:

```
  process (clk, rst)
  begin --process
    if rst = '1' then
      st <= s0;
```

so `st` is `s0` when `rst` is `'1'` and then you have written

```
  process(st, input1)
    begin  -- process
      case (st) is
        when (s0) => --initial state
          if input1 = "11" then
            output1 <= "11";
```

so `output1` is `"11"` when `st` is `s0` and `input1` is `"11"`.

Comment: Is it ok to rewrite it to: `process(st, input1)
    begin  -- process
      case (st) is
        when (s0) => --initial state
          if input1 = "11"  and rst = '0' then
            output1 <= "11";`

Comment: No, it is not OK. `rst` is asynchronous and therefore must only be used to reset flip-flops. (That is very important. To use `rst` as you suggest would result in an asynchronous design. Don't go there.)  What behaviour are you after? It sounds like you want the `output1` to be `"00"` when reset is applied, but not if it isn't. That isn't what reset is for. Reset is to put a design in a known state, which it should then stay in after releasing reset until something else changes. (The act of releasing reset should NOT change the state of a design.)

Comment: That is exactly what I want, on reset high I will like to put my design in a known state, then it should stay in that state until reset is low and some input changes.

Comment: So, you need to decide what value you want `output1` to have when in state `s0` and input1 is `"11"`; `"00"` or `"11"`?

Comment: I think have solved it by changing the `output1 <= "00"` during the transition from s0 to S1. Now the FSM remains in s0 until  `rst = 0`, then if `input1 <= "11"` the fsm will move to state s1.